# Vue3 - watching changes on all variables in component at once instead of each one?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a few variables in my component. For example:

```
const selectedStudents = computed({
get: get it
set: { set it; search(); }

const selectedTeachers = computed({
get: get it
set: { set it; search(); }


const selectedSchools = computed({
get: get it
set: { set it; search(); }
```

I am wondering if it's possible to make it so that instead of having the `search();` in every set function, I somehow watch changes on ANY of the variables, and if any of them changes, I perform a search. The reason I want this is because currently, in certain situations, I perform as many searches as I have variables (7-8 currently), when it could just be one search instead.

Comment: " watch changes on ANY of the variables" - this is what `watch` and `watchEffect` are for (hence the name)

Comment: If you want to ensure there is only 1 search - you should use debouncing.

Comment: [Watching Multiple Sources](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watching-multiple-sources)